# REGEX for search and exclude combined

Tags: regex

### Overview:

I am trying to combine two REGEX queries into one:

- `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`
- `^(?!(10\.|169\.)).*$`

I wrote this as a two part query. The first part would isolate IPs in a block of text and after I copy and paste this I select everything and that does not being with a 10 or 169.

### Questions:

It seems like I am over complicating this:

- Can anybody see a better way to do this?
- Is there a way to combine these two queries?

Comment: Try `\b(?!(?:10|169)\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b` if you need to extract specific IPs from a larger text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That should be posted as an answer (even though it's trivial to someone knowing regex syntax, it's likely to be useful to others in the future).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That also worked thanks man!

Comment: No idea how that worked if you found Bohemian's solution working. These are different regex patterns to be used in different contexts.

Comment: I can't  post an  answer, my daughter is not sleeping.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both solutions work in Caret text editor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually you are correct only your solution works on a paragraph containing IPs. I tested the below solution on a list of IPs in Caret.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103556/discussion-between-robert-j-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A quick-and-gimme-regex style answer**

[Basic](https://regex101.com/r/tA3gJ4/4) one (whole string looks like an IP): `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$`

[Lite](https://regex101.com/r/tA3gJ4/1) (period-separated 4-digit chunks, a whole word): `\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b`

[Medium](https://regex101.com/r/tA3gJ4/2) (excluding junk like `1.2.4.6.7.9.0`): `(?<!\d\.)\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d+)`

[Advanced 1](https://regex101.com/r/tA3gJ4/3) (not starting with `10` or `169`): `(?<!\d\.)\b(?!(?:1(?:0|69))\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d+)`

[Advanced 2](https://regex101.com/r/tA3gJ4/5) (not ending with `8` or `10`): `(?<!\d\.)\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.(?!(?:8|10)\b)\d+\b(?!\.\d+)`

**Details for the curious**

The `\b` is a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that makes it possible to match exact "words" (entities consisting of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characteters) inside a longer text. So, if we do not want to match `12.12.23.56` inside `g12.12.23.56g`, we use the *Lite* version.

The [**lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) together with the word boundary, make it possible to further restrict the matches. `(?<!\d\.)` - a negative lookbehind - and a `(?!\.\d+)` - a negative lookahead - will fail a match if the IP-resembling substring is preceded with a `digit`+`.` or followed with a `.`+`digit`. So, we do not match `12.12.34.56.78.90899`-like entities with this regex. Choose *Medium* regex for that case.

Now, you need to restrict the matches to those that do not start with some numeric value. You need to make use of either a [**lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), or a [**lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead). **When choosing between a lookbehind or a lookahead solution, prefer the lookahead, because 1) it is less resource consuming, and 2) more flavors support it.** Thus, to fail all matches where IP first number is equal to `10` or `169`, we can use a *negative lookahead anchored **after** the leading word boundary*: `(?!(?:1(?:0|69))\.)`. The syntax is `(?!...)` and inside, we match either `1` followed with `0` and then a `.`, or `1` followed with `69` and then `.`. Note that we could write `(?!10\.|169\.)` but **there is some redundant backtracking overhead** then, as `1` part is repeating. Best practice is to "contract" alternations so that the beginning of each branch did not repeat, make the alternation group more linear. So, use *Advanced 1* regex version to get those IPs.

A similar case is the *Advanced 2* regex for getting some IPs that do not end with some value.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for taking the time to explain this in depth and cite sources that I can read up on!

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just put the anchored negative look ahead at the start:

```
^(?!10\.|169\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

Note: Unnecessary brackets have been removed.

---

To match within a line, ie remove the anchors and use a "word boundary" `\b` as the anchor:

```
\b(?!10\.|169\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: Actually I lied (sorry) this works great on a list of IPs but for a paragraph like format containing IPs something like this should be used: `\b(?!(?:10|169)\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b`

Comment: @rob answer edited. You can probably drop the trailing `\b` if you want.